# Why $d(A,B)$ is not always achieved when $B$ is closed?

Tags: general-topology

We know that in a metric space $(E,d)$ if $A,B\neq\emptyset$ are compact and disjoint then there exists $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $d(a,b)=d(A,B)$

but how to prove that if $A$ is compact and $B$ juste closed then $d(A,B)$ is not always achieved?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E = \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ with the usual metric.

Then $A=[-2,-1]$ is compact and $B=(0,1]$ is closed, but the distance between them ($d(A,B) = 1$) is never achieved $(d(a,b) >1$ for all $a \in A, b \in B$).

Comment: I was trying to think of an example if $E$ is complete but nothing came to mind. This is much simpler.

Comment: $C_{E} B=]-\infty,0[\cup ]1,+\infty$ is always open ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. A set $O$ is open in $E$ **iff** there is some open $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $O = E \cap U$. So, since $[0,1]^c$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, the set $(-\infty,0) \cup (1,\infty)$ will be open in $E$.

Comment: my question is $C_{E}B$ is open because it is the union of two open sets ? if yes why $]-\infty, 0[$ is open on R\{0}

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $C_E B$.

Comment: the complement of $B$ in $E$

Comment: $E \setminus B = (\infty, 0) \cup (1,\infty)$. Both $(\infty, 0),(1,\infty)$ are open in $\mathbb{R}$, we see that $(\infty, 0) \cap E = (\infty, 0)$ is open and similarly for the other set.

Comment: (+1) Nice example. I was blocked by thinking about spaces where closed and bounded implied compact.